# Solving the algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve this: $$x-40={-400\over x}$$
The answer must be $x=20$
Please give step by step explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $x\neq 0$, multiply both sides of the equation by $x$ to get: 
$$x\cdot(x-40)  =-400$$ Next expand the left hand side and re-arrange to get: 
$$x^2-40x+400=0$$. To factor the left hand side, look for two numbers that when you multiply you get 400 and add to -40. Doing that yields $$(x-20)(x-20) =0.$$ You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: I am not clear about how $x^2-40x+400$ becomes $(x-20)(x-20)$.Please explain it too.

Comment: I thought I made it clear in my answer. anyways, you could use the quadratic formula or recall that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ or in particular $(a-b)^2=(a-b)(a-b)=a^2-2ab+b^2$ with $a=x$ and $b=20$

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Multiply through by x.

Step 2. Move everything to one side.

Step 3. Use the quadratic formula.

Step 4. Conclude that $x=20$.

Comment: Please show your way by including the calculation process, for each step

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the equation gives :

$ x^2 - 40x + 400 = 0$

$ => {(x-20)}^2 = 0 $

$=> x = 20 $